If you execute your rights to erase personal data, is that destruction of evidence?
A is involved in a criminal activity, and the evidence lies with a 3rd-party service.
That service is subject to a statutory right to erasure provision (let's assume the proof is not data that legally needs to be kept despite the right of erasure).
A decides, unknowing of any investigation, to execute their right to erase their data in the service.
They then get caught, and when executing a search warrant, the service doesn't hold the data anymore.
Is executing the right to erasure a destruction of evidence?

Also: It would be the 3rd-party service that deletes the data, not the data subject

This question already has answers here:  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15987/are-you-required-to-act-to-preserve-evidence-that-will-otherwise-be-destroyed?rq=1  and here:  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/90516/would-i-be-risking-being-guilty-of-destruction-of-evidence-any-time-i-clear-data?rq=1

Voting to reopen. Neither link has answers addressing this question.

You have to intend to mislead and know that it may be required in a judicial proceeding
new-south-wales
s317 of the Crimes Act 1900:

A person who, with intent to mislead any judicial tribunal in any judicial proceeding--
(a) suppresses, conceals, destroys, alters or falsifies anything knowing that it is or may be required as evidence in any judicial proceeding,

Note that this requires actual knowledge of an actual judicial proceeding, not suspicion of a hypothetical investigation that might lead to charges against you in the future.
So, if there is no current judicial proceeding, or you are unaware of such a proceeding, you cannot tamper with evidence, even if you intend to prevent information from coming to light about your own or someone else's crimes. Note that information about judicial proceedings is published, so you are deemed to know about it even if you are not actually aware of it.
Pro tip: don’t make or keep records of your crimes.

The plain language of the statute doesn't seem to require the actual-knowledge requirement; is that a judicial interpretation? If so, I think it would be inconsistent with the common-law trend.

@bdb484, Intent to mislead logically follows having prior knowledge of that which you intend to mislead.  si quid verum erit...

Correct. If you know the court exists, you can act with intent to mislead it, even without actual knowledge of an actual proceeding. So I think we're in agreement?

@bdb484 No, there has to be an actual proceeding happening now where the evidence may be relevant.

@DaleM Yes, I understand that that's the position you're taking. I'm wondering whether you have any law supporting it, as it seems like an outlier and contrary to the statute's plain language.

@bdb484 you can’t have the intent to deceive a non-existent judicial proceeding. I don’t have any case law because they don’t charge people for destroying documents they don’t care about

@DaleM You definitely can. If I see you walking into the police station to rat me out for insider trading, I can immediately start shredding incriminating evidence. Is it really the law in Australia that that's not a crime as long as I finish before the prosecutor has time to initiate a judicial proceeding?
